# what determine the call of the override method

Tags: java, overriding

```
public class Superclass{

    void method1(){
        method0();
    }

    void method0(){
        System.out.println("superclass"); 
    }

}



public class Subclass extends Superclass{

    void method0(){
        System.out.println("subclass");
    }

}


public class Runclass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Subclass().method1();
    }

}
```

This code print out - subclass.

Let say it is

```
new Superclass().method1();
```

then, it will print out - superclass

**Is it the method called depend on the instance that call the method?**

Comment: `method1()` is not the overridden method at all in your code!!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained Spotted !!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what object method is called. If the method is called on parent object, parents method will be called, but if the method is called on child object then child class method will be called. If method is not overridden then always parent class method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Its a example of `Dynamic Method Dispatch` (Run time polymorphism).
In Dynamic method dispatch call of an overridden method is resolve at the run time.
When u call

```
new Superclass().method1();
```

the output is - `superclass`
Because Superclass does not have any information about subclass.
& when you call

```
new Subclass().method1();
```

the output is - `subclass`
Because when overridden method is called, java determines which version of method to be execute based upon the type of the object being referred at the time of call occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to explain it in a better way, when a function, say your `method()`is overridden in the `subclass` and you are calling `method()` with an instance of the `superclass` , the `superclass` object have no idea about the `method()` being overridden and it will run its own version of `method()`. In fact any changes made to the `subclass` is invisible to the `superclass`.Hence any instance of the `superclass` won't be able to access the `subclass`'s overridden `method()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Polymorphism.**

May be you forgot this

```
public class Subclass extends ParentClass{
```

Untill unless you ovveride the method in child class it calls only `parent method`.

```
new Superclass().method1();
```

here I super class instance is there so super class  `method1` calls

And if you call

```
 new Subclass().method1();
```

`subclasses` ovveridden  `method1` calls.

And I would like to suggest this [**tutorial**](http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/dynamic-polymorphism/) for clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

*Sub* Class must extend *Super* Class :

```
public class Subclass extends SuperClass{

    void method0(){
        System.out.println("subclass");
    }

}
```

When calling `SubClass().method()` the priority of calling will be to subClass's method, the output is

> subclass

But in this case :

```
public class Subclass extends SuperClass{

    }
```

The output will be :

> superclass

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass obj = new SubClass();
        obj.print();
    }
}

class SuperClass {

    SuperClass() {
        print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("SuperClass");
    }
}
```

The above code will print:

```
SubClass
SubClass
SubClass
```

What is important to remember is that the method to be executed is determined by the JVM at runtime, based on the type of the actual object and not by the type of its reference variable.. Here, when an object of class SubClass is created, first SubClass's default constructor is called, which invokes SuperClass's constructor. SuperClass's constructor in turn calls print(). Here, since the class of the actual object is SubClass, SubClass's print is selected instead of SuperClass's print.